# How to crawl the google news page using scrapy

Tags: google-api, web-crawler, scrapy, scrape

How to crawl google news using scrapy Python

I have crawl the content of google news..

How is it make the task

Answer (score -1):

According to http://news.google.com/robots.txt, crawling is disallowed.